# Do steel need register Twig Extensions in the services.yml?

Tags: php, symfony

I learning Symfony3 on https://knpuniversity.com. Now on create their own filters in Twig (https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-services/create-twig-extension). In this video the author creates a class filter, but when using this filter in the Twig template:

```
<dd>{{ genus.funFact|markdownify }}</dd>
```

Symfony crashes with the error, and the author of the video says that the filter has used need to say Symfony about new filter Twig'. This is done using the register Twig extension as service in the `services.yml`. But, I have it all working, without errors, without any registrations in `service.yml`.

Do steel need register Twig Extensions in the `services.yml`?

Or is now not required and determines its own Twig extension?

I have a Symfony 3.3.6 (in video used 3.0.0).

Here listing my `service.yml`:

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']


    AppBundle\Service\MarkdownTransformer:
        arguments:
            - '@markdown.parser'
            - '@doctrine_cache.providers.my_markdown_cache'
        public: true


#    AppBundle\Twig\MarkdownExtension:
#        arguments: ['@AppBundle\Service\MarkdownTransformer']
#        tags:
#            - { name: twig.extension }
#        public: true
```

In the bottom I'm added the settings block, which registers a new TWIG extension. Without this block, Symfony throws an exception (in the author of the lesson). But I have everything working without this block. So for example, I have it commented out.

Comment: Can you show your `services.yml`?

Comment: Starting in S3.3, autowire can apply tags based on what a class implements.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#autoconfiguring-tags And it automatically defines all classes as services by default except for a few directories excluded in the config section of services.yml. The magic continues to grow.

Comment: Thanks all for reply! Listing my `service.yml` I added in topic start post.